# is there an easy way to assign the highest value across each row for each category based on a priority in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

observe the following table

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | Y |
| A | N |
| A | NA |
| B | N |
| B | NA |
| C | NA |

the priority order is Y,N,NA so in this case every col2 where col1 is A should get Y, B should get N, and C should stay NA.

expected result

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | Y |
| A | Y |
| A | Y |
| B | N |
| B | N |
| C | NA |

I was thinking of making a temporary table substituting Y,N,NA with 3,2,1 then doing a rank over partition, then joining it with the original table and substituting back.

Comment: Sample data is i good start, but you should also show us the expected result. (Aka [mcve].)

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: @jarlh OP did mention of using "rank over partition" so I guess at least MySQL v8 or MariaDB that supports window function?

Comment: What if `A` don't have `Y`? or `B` no `N`? or `C` no `NA`?

Comment: @FaNo_FN, could be so, or perhaps OP isn't aware of version differences.